# JNA calling C++ object from DLL - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure class has unknown or zero size

Tags: java, c++, pointers, dll, jna

I'm trying to access with JNA to my simple DLL, written on C++ (Windows 32 bit, Java 8, JNA  5.2.0, Visual Studio 2017 C++). The DLL has function which creates object. And I want to get the pointer on object and access to object function's inside JAVA-code.
I receive JNA-Pointer to the native object and try to initialyze it's Java-Structure implementation.
And here I have Exception during JNA-Structure initialization:

```
    public IMyClass(Pointer p) { 
            super(p);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure class edu.nyu.cpptest.cpplib.CppLibDemo$CppLib$IMyClass has unknown or zero size (ensure all fields are public)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1374)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1158)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1110)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:350)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:202)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:193)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:189)  at edu.nyu.cpptest.cpplib.CppLibDemo$CppLib$IMyClass.(CppLibDemo.java:30)  at edu.nyu.cpptest.cpplib.CppLibDemo.(CppLibDemo.java:52)

C++ Code:

MyClass.h:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) IMyClass {
public: 
    //int value;
    virtual int getValue() = 0;
    virtual void increment() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public IMyClass {
public:
    int value;
    MyClass();
    MyClass(int v);
    int getValue();
    void increment();
};  

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) IMyClass* createMyClass();
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {this->value = 0;}
MyClass::MyClass(int v) { this->value = v; }
int MyClass::getValue() { return value; }
void MyClass::increment() { value++; }
```

cpplib.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IMyClass* createMyClass() {
    MyClass *mcl = new MyClass(0);
    return mcl;
}
```

Java code:

```
public class CppLibDemo {
    public interface CppLib extends StdCallLibrary  {
        CppLib INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("cpplib.dll", CppLib.class);
        Pointer createMyClass();
        class IMyClass extends Structure {
            interface Increment extends Callback {
                public void invoke();
            }
            interface GetValue extends Callback {
                public int invoke();
            }
            public IMyClass() { }
            public IMyClass(Pointer p) { 
                super(p); 
                super.read();
            }
            Increment increment;
            GetValue getValue;
            //public int value;//I tried to add 'value' field in IMyClass-native and java code
            //public void read() {
            //    value = (int)readField("value");
            //    super.read();
            //}
        }
    }
    CppLib.IMyClass myClass;
    public CppLibDemo() {
        Pointer ptr = CppLib.INSTANCE.createMyClass();
        myClass = new CppLib.IMyClass(ptr);
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return myClass.getValue.invoke();
    }
    public void increment() {
        myClass.increment.invoke();
    }
}
```

I also tried to move 'value'-field from MyClass to the it's parent IMyClass in C++ code and declare value-field in IMyClass in Java code. In this case I also have exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class edu.nyu.cpptest.cpplib.CppLibDemo$CppLib$IMyClass returns names ([]) which do not match declared field names ([value])
>   at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:1088)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1233)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1158)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:350)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:202)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:193)  at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:189)  at edu.nyu.cpptest.cpplib.CppLibDemo$CppLib$IMyClass.(CppLibDemo.java:30)

I tested this with simple console application, which loads my DLL in Viusual Studio and it works fine.
And I also can call my DLL through JNI using SWIG java & DLL-wrapper generation. It's interesting, if this is possible with JNA.

Comment: JNA doesn't support C++, try JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Answer (score 1):

The Java structure needs to have public fields that match those of the native structure and it needs to declare those fields in the proper order. Typically your Java code will have an annotation that does this:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"value"})
public class ExampleStruct extends Structure {
    public int value;

    // rest of the implementation...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps to fix this exception and go a bit forward. Now the next step is to iniyialyze MyClass.increment variable correctly, because it's null in myClass.increment.invoke().